# how to use messenger view as conversation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am developing a messenger software. How to show conversation of message like facebook. I know data repeater. But  i don't know to show the bubble in background with different color

[image: facebook Conversation]

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a repeater control to display each message (composed by a div tag and span tag with text), and apply css rules to format as you like (setting background-image for the image and the bubble pointer and border-radius to round the divs)